# Connecting to DynamoDB from an EC2 instance running in an ECS cluster with VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 instance running inside an ECS cluster with VPC.

On the instance, I need to run a ECS task that needs access to DynamoDB.

When I try running the same task using Fargate, I can use the `assignPublicIp = 'ENABLED'` option to allow my task to have access to other AWS services, and everything works fine.

However, the `assignPublicIp` option is not available for the EC2 launch type, and I cannot figure out how to allow my EC2 instance have access to other AWS services.

I read the AWS docs and followed guides like [this one](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb-tutorial.html) to setup VPC endpoint for DynamoDB.

I also made sure that there aren't any network access restrictions by making sure that inbound/outbound rules for my NACL and security group for the VPC are wide open (at least for the sake of testing).

Here is how the rules look like, for both NACL and my security group:

[image]

[image]

Finally, I used the `VPC > Reachability Analyzer` to check if AWS can detect any problems regarding the connection path between my EC2 instance and DynamoDB, but the analysis reported a `Reachable` status.

It basically told me that there was no issues regarding establishing a connection along the following path:

- Network interface for my EC2 instance (source)
- Security group for the VPC
- NACL for the VPC
- Route table for the VPC

  - which includes the following route added by the VPC endpoint for DynamoDB
  - **Destination**: pl-02cd2c6b (com.amazonaws.us-east-1.dynamodb, 3.218.182.0/24, 3.218.180.0/23, 52.94.0.0/22, 52.119.224.0/20)
  - **Target**: the endpoint ID (e.g., `vpce-foobar`)
- VPC endpoint for DynamoDB (destination)

Despite AWS telling me that I have a "Reachable" status, I still think it might be a network reachability problem, because when I run the task, the script I am running gets stuck right after it makes a GetItem call to DynamoDB.

If it was a permission error or an invalid parameter issue, I would get an error immediately, but everything just "hangs" there, until the task eventually times out.

Any pointers on what I might be missing here, or other workarounds would be very appreciated.

Thank you.

#### EDIT 1 (2021/02/13):

So I went back to the AWS docs to see if I had missed anything in setting up the VPC endpoints. I originally had one setup for DynamoDB, but since I also need to use S3 in my service, I went ahead and setup a Gateway VPC Endpoint for S3 too (I also wanted to see if the issue I am having is a generic network problem, or specific to DynamoDB).

Then, I made some changes to my script to try to make a call to S3 (to get the bucket's location, for simplicity) as the very first thing to do. I knew that the call would end up timing out, so I wanted to trigger the error immediately upon starting my script execution.

I waited until my task would eventually fail because of the timeout, and this time I noticed something interesting.

Here is the error logs I got when the task failed:

[image]

The IP address that my task was trying to reach was `52.85.146.194:443`.

And here are the IP addresses that I found in the managed prefix list for S3, which I found in the VPC console:

[image]

The IP address I got the timeout error from is not on the list. Could this be a hint to the cause of the issue? Or am I missing something and there is actually nothing wrong with that?

Comment: Which network mode are you using for the task? I suggest reading this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html

Comment: I am using the `awsvpc` mode

Comment: In that case you need to be using the ENI assigned to the ECS task in the reachability analyzer, instead of the EC2 instance. Also, some things to check: The subnet the ECS task is deployed to has a route to the DynamoDB endpoint in its route table? The VPC has `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport` enabled.

Comment: Yes. With the reachability analyzer, I actually tried both approach, one where I set the EC2 instance itself as the source, and another where I set the ENI assigned to the ECS task as the source. 

Both approaches showed a "Reachable" state.

I also made sure that the subnets the ECS task is deployed to has a route to the DynamoDB endpoint in its route table. 

I also made sure that the VPC has both of those options enabled.

Comment: @MarkB I added some updates